# Adding extra tag field to Django Wagtails StreamBlock

Tags: django, wagtail

I am trying to add an H1 tag option to Wagtails StreamBlock and although it adds it as a selection, I am not getting expected results in the browser; the H1 tag is not being created.

Here is my code

```
class DemoStreamBlock(StreamBlock):
    h1 = CharBlock(icon='title', classname='title')
    h2 = CharBlock(icon='title', classname='title')
    ...
```

And the result in the browser is shown in the screenshot below.  I know I am missing something simple - any help would be appreciates.  Thank  you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Totally forgot the streamfield.html file in my includes folder.  Just add

`{% if child.block_type == 'h1' %} <h1>{{ child }}</h1>`